# stop video when another tab is clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using bootstrap tabs to toggle between videos in my website but I have a problem. When I click on another tab the video in the first tab keeps playing, so I searched and I could tell that it had something to do with javascript! yeah I don't know any thing about javascript just some html,css,php, and sql but no javascript. so if any one can help me I would really appreciate the help ((I use a lot of video hosting sites like youtube, dailymotion, ok.ru and the lest goes on) if any one can help me with the some code I will really appreciate that!
here is my code

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs centered">
    <li class="active"><a data-toggle="tab" href="#video1">video 1</a></li>
    <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#video2">video 2</a></li>
    <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#video3">video 3</a></li>
</ul>

<div class="tab-content">
    <div id="video1" class="tab-pane fade in active" style="padding:5px">
        <div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9">
          <iframe class="embed-responsive-item" src="'.$rows['video1'].'" allowfullscreen></iframe>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="video2" class="tab-pane fade" style="padding:5px">
        <div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9">
            <iframe class="embed-responsive-item" src="'.$rows['video2'].'" allowfullscreen></iframe>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="video3" class="tab-pane fade" style="padding:5px">
        <div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9">
            <iframe class="embed-responsive-item" src="'.$rows['video3'].'" allowfullscreen></iframe>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I think you actually can't do this, because of the "[Same-origin policy](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy)".

In clear, a website A, yours, can't use javascript/datas on a website B via iframe.
You could have do this with the video player hosted on your server (only website A in this case).

Answer (score 0):

You can use `hidden.bs.tab` event to handle the code for pausing the video.
This event is fired when the tab is is fully hidden. 
bootstrap tabs documentation: [here](http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_ref_js_tab.asp)

**JS:**

```
$('a[data-toggle="tab"]').on('hidden.bs.tab', function (e) {
  var video_element= $(e.target);
  //Your code for pausing the video
  });
```